# Disable colors and format to source code in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, colors, format

Is it possible to disable formatting and colors to source code in Eclipse.
I want my java code look like the poor notepad (black and white, etc). don't ask why, I just need answers. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a quick way to do this as it is such an unusual thing to do. But you can change the syntax coloring options in the Preferences in 'Java > Editor > Syntax Coloring'.

Answer (score 1):

Changing syntax coloring options as suggested earlier is a good way to achieve that.

You can also consider just not using the Java editor and using the plain text editor instead: to do so, either open your files with `right-click > Open With > Other...` and select the regular Text Editor. From the Editor Selection dialog, you should be able to override the default editor for your Java files to this Text Editor.

Note that the text editor doesn't provide completion, or documentation on hover, but you'll still get validation/problem reporting.